# Trying to get form validation working with jQueryUI image array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to only allow the user to submit the form when the validation has returned true and they have dragged the images into the correct order. Currently, I have the form input elements working but there seems to be a bug where the user can still submit the form even if the images are in the wrong order. I have two submit buttons one which re-orders all the images in the array and one that I want to validate if all the data is correct. I currently have the onclick button on the submit button to `onclick="return valid();`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think it might be something with two submit buttons? Can someone please help. I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery.

#### HTML:

```
<form action="https://stackoverflow.com" method="POST" onSubmit="" class="a">Name :
  <input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <br/>Address :
  <input type="text" class="text" name="address" id="address" />
  <br/>email :
  <input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" />
  <br/>
  <input type="hidden" id="image_order" name="image_order" value="order" />
  <ul id="sortable" style="width: 524px;">
    <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">
      <img src="1.png" width="100" height="90" />
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">
      <img src="2.png" width="100" height="90" />
    </li>
    <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">
      <img src="3.png" width="100" height="90" />
    </li>
    <li id="4" class="ui-state-default">
      <img src="4.png" width="100" height="90" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <input name="Submit" value="RE-ORDER" type="submit" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="return valid();" />
</form>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
      cursor: 'crosshair',
      update: function (event, ui) {
        var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
        order = JSON.stringify(order);
        console.log(order);
        correct = JSON.stringify(["4", "3", "2", "1"]);
        if (order == correct) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
      var valid = true,
      message = '';
      $('form input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.val()) {
          var inputName = $this.attr('name');
          valid = false;
          message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
        }
      });
      if (!valid) {
        alert(message);
        console.log("not valid");
      } else {
        //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        console.log("valid");
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of type on input tag.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onsubmit="return valid();" />
```

instead of button type, onclick handler.

Checking return value can in onsubmit handler only.

Comment: Thanks but the problem I'm having seems to be getting both the input fields as well as the images submitting together. It allows me currently to submit the form even if order is not equal to the specified array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="reorder" value="RE-ORDER" name="reorder"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
...

$(window).load(function () {
  $(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
      cursor: 'crosshair'
      // update callback function is unnecessary.
      // the valid local variable in callback function can not be accessed when you are about to submit.
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    $("#reorder").on('click', function() {
      // re-order routine
    })
    $('#submit').on('submit', function () {
      // Check validation
      //    checking arrange of images & empty values..
      // you have to return false if requirement is incorrect.
  });
});
```